# Searching 2D Array for single element - Scala

Tags: scala, search, multidimensional-array, methods

I'm coding a method that will search if an element exists in a 2D array (shown below).
While writing, my IDE keeps saying Unit does not take parameters for the "column".
Can someone explain, please? Thank you in advance.

```
    def Array2DScan(elementDetect : Unit, array: Array[Unit],ArrayRow : Int, ArrayColumn: Int): Unit ={
  for (row <- 0 to ArrayRow){
    for(column <- 0 to ArrayColumn){
      val Result = array(row)(column)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you at least know that is **Unit**?  Your code has simply too many problems that it seems you do not really understand the language yet.

Comment: yeah, I just started learning so still got some work to do

Comment: Yeah, I get that. My point is that if you didn't understand the basis like **types** doing something more advanced would be painful, I would also recommend asking in [**gitter**](https://gitter.im/scala/scala) instead since the realtime chat can be more helpful for a newcomer.

Comment: thanks man, i'll check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unit is something like void in java and other languages, you should not use unit in your functions because the only possible value for that is "()".
My suggestion is that you use something like either of these:

```
def arrayScanner[T](elementDetect: T, array: Array[T]) ....
```

or:

```
def arrayScanner(element: Any, array: Array[Any]) ....
```

which i suggest the first one, and also try not to use for loops, and name your functions and methods starting lowercase.